# How to use data in ETSI MEC Platform, MEC App

Tags: iot

I am currently exploring the ETSI MEC platform for my research, but I am having difficulty finding documentation or examples related to the raw data flow within the ETSI MEC ecosystem. Specifically, I am interested in understanding how data (such as air temperature readings from a temperature sensor) flows through the MEC system.

While I have come across documentation regarding the MEC app lifecycle and MEC app management system (MEC 010-2, MEC 011), information on the actual data flow seems to be elusive. Could you please provide insights or direct me to relevant resources that explain the data flow within the ETSI MEC ecosystem?

I try some documents of ETSI MEC, but I cant get information that i want